# Application Defined or Object Defined Error on QueryTable

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm trying to take data from a table in SQL and export it to a worksheet using VBA.

I have been unable to figure out how to do this without creating a new data connection each time.

Here is what I have been doing as of now:

I am putting the SQL query into a cell and giving the variables names like '#ID' and "Date". In the macro, I am replacing the data within those variables with the actual information. That has not given me any problems thus far as the query runs without issue when using SQL. To export the data from SQL to my worksheet, I am using code that works in other workbooks; however when I run it in this workbook, I am getting the error "Application Defined or Object Defined Error". Here is the full macro:

```vb
Sub CurrentBreakout()

Dim SQLString As String
Dim ID As String
Dim Date As String
Dim year As String
Dim daycount As String

SQLString = Range("CurrentBreakout") 'This is the range where the query is stored 
ID = Range("ID")
Date = Range("CurrMonth")
year = Range("CurrYear")
daycount = Range("CurrDayCount")

SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "#ID", ID)
SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "#Date", Date)
SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "#CurrDayCount", daycount)
SQLString = Replace(SQLString, "#CurrYear", year)


 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
   "ODBC;DSN=____________;UID=________;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=________;DATABASE=_______;" _
        , Destination:=Range("CurrCon")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = SQLString
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_CurrCon"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

End Sub
```

I am getting the error at ".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False". This is probably not the best way to complete this task, but it is the only way I know.

Comment: .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False is where it actually executes that block of code so it could be anything before that. Date and Year are functions so they can't be used as variable names. Try changing those and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL query - you could have characters in there that need to be escaped in VBA.